# finding the array index value for the selected android spinner item

Tags: android, android-spinner

during registration user can select the titleName from a android Spinner. Im loading data to the Spinner from xml class. I want to pass the titleName as well as title ID,

How can I get the value of selected titleName's array index?
eg- if user selected Mr then i want to pass the value 0.

my java code

```
states = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.title_array);

            titleSP = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.registerTitle);

            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, states);
            dataAdapter
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            titleSP.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {

                    String TitleName = titleSP.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

MY title.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="title_prompt">Choose the title</string>
    <string-array name="title_array">
        <item>Mr</item>
        <item>Mrs</item>
        <item>Miss</item>
        <item>Dr</item>
        <item>Rev</item>
        <item>Ms</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Comment: it is given in the listener.

Comment: @njzk2 can u show me how to do using the code please

Comment: I assume you have a listener that is called when an item of the spinner is selected?

Comment: Spinner + read the doc = `getSelectedItemPosition`

Answer (score 0):

it the `position` parameter in your Adapter. You can retrieve it implementing `OnItemClickListener`. The third parameter of [onItemClick](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html)
is the value you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

Use the Spinners OnItemClickListener

```
spinner.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String[] titles = getResources().getStringArray(R.id.title_array);
                String selectedTitle = titles[position];
            }
        });
```

The position variable gives the position of the item in the spinner, which you can match directly to the position of the title in the data source.

Edit:
You can use the built in method of a spinner to get the current selected item position. So if you select the first item, you would get selected item position 0. As this is based on your data source, selected item position 0, would be the same as index position 0 in R.id.title_array which would be "Mr".

```
titleSP.getSelectedItemPosition();
```

Comment: Please check my edit. If it is correct and what you want, mark as correct and upvote.

Comment: there was a issue bz of button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { >> ur idea is correct but this is not what i wanted so i cant vote for u. sry.. btw now i'm done with this part. thanks bro